# Error when trying to install AMD drivers

Tags: ati, 15.10

I have Lenovo thinkpad S440. When trying to install latest AMD drivers i get a message saying "Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed."

My GPU is HD Radeon 8670M. It should be supported as stated [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64).

Also, i use Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes last version of the amd driver has problems to detect the GPU, try installing an older version [from here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous?os=Linux%20x86_64)